# Save file generated by canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: javascript, canvas

I made some `png` using `canvas.toDataURL()`.
I want to save it to folder that have some `png` using download dialog.
But I don't know how to make folder and to use download dialog.
Please advise me.

Comment: Have you any code examples?

Comment: Also what do you want from user? User must save your png local by using download dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure there's no way to create an arbitrary folder on your client's computer. It seems to me like that would be a massive security problem.

If you want to create a link to download a file, just use the download attribute on your a tag.

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAAXNSR0IArs4
    c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABoSU
    RBVDhPvYxLFoAwCAN7/0sjJRFCW135nIWSX4d1xgaDm6b32FlMinjr0Aaa1
    gDHE21QIsAN1MFR2pniw4ED2Rrv/D+g3sh0fvMCUWgw0EEKEDVCSwo10HhB
    01bSABwc/gWUAK3E7AJgQR/9VKyAfgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
download="myimage.png">Download this image</a>.
```

Comment: Keep in mind not every browser that supports `canvas.toDataURL()` supports the download attribute.